How to Safely Extend a Short Wire for a Bathroom Exhaust Fan Motor?
I’m replacing the motor on my bathroom exhaust fan, but the wire from the motor is too short to reach the socket inside the housing (see attached image). What are the safest and most effective options for extending the wire or adapting it to connect securely? Should I use a specific type of extension cord, or is there a recommended method for splicing the wire? Any safety tips or guidelines would be greatly appreciated!

No attached image. Use the "edit" link below the post and try again.

Without the pic no one can say.  But odds are you are going to need to add a junction box and cover.  Whether or not you have to cut a hole in the ceiling depends whether you have access to the fan from above—again, no pic.

@Huesmann your comment is a great answer.

Without a pic I can't tell, but I assume OP is talking about an old style of exhaust fan where the housing actually had an outlet in it, and the fan motor had a 2 prong plug on it that you'd plug in. If you look up part # S0696B000 it should bring up pics, for anyone curious.
If that's the case, can you just rotate the new motor to bring it closer to the outlet? They're usually symmetrical AFAIK, and you shouldn't need much length to reach the outlet.

@PeteB. perhaps, but I couldn't decide—if the OP adds a pic it may provide some clarity that my make my answer obsolete.  Just hedging my bets!
